# How to create a serverless endpoint in aws sagemaker?

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, aws-serverless

I am recreating an endpoint currently working in SageMaker for inference by a serverless endpoint. I am using one of the AWS maintained baseimages: `763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-inference:1.5-cpu-py3`.

Everything works when I choose non-serverless (i.e. provisioned option for endpoint configuration), but when I try to create one with the serverless option, it fails. The error messages from the logs in cloud watch are below, starting with python and log4j error at the end.

> OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this
> system, assuming 256k. python: can't open file
> '/usr/local/bin/deep_learning_container.py': [Errno 13] Permission
> denied. Warning: MMS is using non-default JVM parameters:
> -XX:-UseContainerSupport Failed to reap children process, log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> logs/mms_log.log (No such file or directory)

I have set memory to the maximum allowed memory size of 6GB for the serverless option. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Could you share the code where you are creating the serverless endpoint as well?

Answer (score 0):

How big is your model? If you are using the SageMaker SDK, have you set `model_server_workers` in your PyTorchModel?

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='', 
                             role=role, 
                             .
                             .
                             .
                             model_server_workers=1
                            )
```

Kindly test using just 1 worker or leave `model_server_workers` as None, as that set one worker per vCPU.